# google event tracking - how to exclude subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I am new to google analytics and did not really found anything what appears to be what I want.

I have a site:
*https://www.example.com*

domain would be `example.com`

I also have a subsite for testing which I do not want to track at all:

*https://www.test.example.com*

How would I exclude those events?
Setting up my tracker like this... :

```
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto', 'myTracker');
```

will result in getting events for all subsites of `mysite.com`.

Update:
Actually the domain I want to track is like:

*https://www.prod.example.com*

So tried filtering, excluding other `subdomain` *test.example.com* :

[image]

..without success.
Moreover I would not know how to exclude multiple subdomains.

Sorry for the german interace. Filter is :
Exclude->Pattern->Applyto->All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create include and exclude filters to track or block hits from subdomains. In your case, for example, you could create a filter that excludes all hits (like your event) from `www.test.example.com`. You can't direct where hits go in the hit itself, but you can filter them out in your views.

Edit: to exclude data from a specific subdomain, you would need to use a `Hostname` filter. It looks like you are filtering by Request URI (`Anforderungs-URI`) which would not work as that refers to the page path and not the hostname.

Comment: thx I'll take a look again at those filter options. When I checked it I did not find a proper filter but I'll look againg.